# Separate data with a comma CSV Python

Tags: python, csv, delimiter

I have some data that needs to be written to a CSV file. The data is as follows

```
A        ,B    ,C
a1,a2    ,b1   ,c1
a2,a4    ,b3   ,ct
```

The first column has comma inside it. The entire data is in a list that I'd like to write to a CSV file, delimited by commas and without disturbing the data in column A. How can I do that? Mentioning `delimiter = ','` splits it into four columns on the whole.

Comment: what does your actual list look like? Is each row a string?

Comment: @DavidMarx Yes. It looks like this ['A','B','C']['a1,a2','b1','c1']['a2,a4','b3','ct']

Comment: @vanandy what's your expected output?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Just to write to a csv file with correct headers and correct corresponding column data.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `csv.writer` from the `csv` module.

```
import csv

data =  [['A','B','C']
         ['a1,a2','b1','c1']
         ['a2,a4','b3','ct']]

fname = "myfile.csv"    
with open(fname,'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in data:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

https://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.writer

Comment: The filemode should be `'wb'` now `w`... (and you can also use `writer.writerows(data)` to avoid the explicit `for` loop)

Comment: how you get the data list like above from the csv file?

Comment: @AvinashRaj If I understand your question correctly, with the `csv.reader` class.

Comment: @DavidMarx Thank you. But my data is like ['A','B','C']['a1,a2','b1','c1']['a2,a4','b3','ct'] and is not a list of lists like you mentioned in your answer, if that'd make a difference because that didn't work for me.

Comment: @vanandy is it a string?

Comment: It is. But I converted it to a list by doing [data,] because my data is looking weird and thought converting it to a list would make it easier. @vks

Comment: @vanandy please provide a reproducible example, including an *explicit* representation of your data. I'm sorry my solution didn't fit your needs, but it was based on my understanding of how you described your data. Help me help you.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use the `csv` module since the ',' in the first column is already part of your data, this will work:

```
with open('myfile.csv', 'w') as f:
    for row in data:
        f.write(', '.join(row))
        f.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below.

Code:

```
import csv
import re
with open('infile.csv', 'r') as f:
    lst = []
    for line in f:
        lst.append(re.findall(r',?(\S+)', line))
    with open('outfile.csv', 'w', newline='') as w:
        writer = csv.writer(w)
        for row in lst:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Output:

```
A,B,C
"a1,a2",b1,c1
"a2,a4",b3,ct
```

Comment: what do you need `sys` for?